# Getting 421 code with HttpUrlConnection in Java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Here's my code to get the response of a `GET` httpRequest to have it's body response

```
HttpURLConnection con = HttpUtilities.createProxyHttpConnection(httpUrl);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
con.connect();
System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());
System.out.println(con.getResponseCode());
```

The output is :

```
Misdirected Request
421
```

Tried to search but can't find any help

*Note 1* : When I execute a `HTTP GET` with `SoapUI`, I can get the result

*Note 2* : The URL is a https